# Running SQL Server based Program Via VPN

Tags: vpn, sql-server-2008

I have recently set up a site-to-site VPN. Location A has a PC running windows 7 (we'll call it Computer1) that acts as a server for a point of sale program. The program uses SQL Server 2008 to store all of its data. Other PC's on that network serve as workstations that run the program off of Computer1 so the shortcut for the program on the workstations points to \Computer1\POSSoftware\pos.exe

From the remote location where I am trying to access and open this program, I am not able to access any of the other networks PC's by name, so I am trying to use the IP address. My shortcut from the remote location points to \192.xxx.xxx.xxx\POSSoftware\pos.exe.  When I try to open the program though, I get a runtime error saying that the network path was not found.

I can go to the file explorer and type in the path "\192.xxx.xxx.xxx\POSSoftware" and access Computer1 by the ip address, and see all of the folders and files, so why is it telling me the network path could not be found? I can also open up Sql Server Management Studio on the remote PC And access the database by using the IP address.

I have temporarily disabled the firewalls at both locations on both PC's. The VPN is set up through a watchguard Firewall. I can open up other programs over the VPN connection such as CCleaner and Google Chrome.

Can anyone please give me suggestions as to why I am not able to open this program?

Comment: I'm not certain what the answer is, but I can help you get closer:  it has nothing whatever to do with SQL Server and everything to do with windows file sharing.  Does it ask you for credentials when you try to explore the shared network directory? ("\192.xxx.xxx.xxx\POSSoftware")

Comment: Currently, NO. I can't quite remember if it asked for credentials the very first time that I opened that directory

Comment: but it hasn't been asking for credentials

Comment: And i am able to go into that directory and open other programs like CCleaner or Chrome, but this POSSoftware won't open

Comment: I'd try this workaround:  Choose a drive letter and map a network drive using specified (saved) credentials and tell it to reconnect at login.  It  will then authenticate the connection at startup.  Then try creating the shortcut using that drive letter.

Comment: Are you saying the .exe won't OPEN or doesn't function?  If it opens but doesn't function then that would appear to be a SQL problem, likely related to a bad or missing ODBC connection.  For a SQL connection you generally would need a defined ODBC connection that A: points to  the 192.xxx.xxx address, and B: has proper SQL credentials embedded in it.

Comment: I tried that workaround but the same thing happened (network path could not be found). The .exe fires, it asks me if i'm sure I wan't to run the program and I click yes, the as it tries to begin loading the program it throws the runtime error. Would it still be an ODBC issue if I am able to access the database through SQL Server Management studio without problems

Comment: Could it be anything to do with the fact that in Sql Server Configuration manager, under TCP/IP none of the ip addresses were enabled and for IP ALL it was using a dynamic port?

Comment: Turns out it was a dns issue. I could not resolve the names of the pc's on the other network. After setting up Dynamic DNS so that I could resolve host names, I was able to run the program just fine.